# SFML. C++. Телепорт и спавн

Tags: c++, sfml

**Доброго времени суток. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, какими методами, функциями реализуется телепорт игрока в платформере c++ (sfml), а именно:

*1) Место спавна игрока.

2) При столкновении с объектом телепортация игрока в определенную точку, либо полное исчезновение игрока с дальнейшим выводом на экран сообщения о конце игры.***

Comment: Не понимаю, как же вы остальную часть игры сделали, если не понимаете, как сделать конкретно это?

Comment: Если вам нужна помощь, лучше общаться вежливо и без наездов. *"какими методами, функциями реализуется телепорт игрока"* *"А если не знаешь как, то зачем вообще"* Ну вам же написали ниже, sfml вам в этом не поможет. Вы сами должны хранить информацию о позиции игрока, и говорить sfml, где его рисовать.

Comment: Вопрос создает впечатление, что часть игры уже сделана. Самая первая вещь, которую сделал бы я, это управление персонажем с клавиатуры. Если у вас это сделано, тогда вы должны уже знать, как перемещать персонажа (поэтому вопрос и показался странным). Если не сделано, тогда непонятно, почему вы, не сделав самой основы, игры спрашиваете про более продвинутые вещи. Вообще, в каком состоянии сейчас игра? Код можете показать?

Comment: Код сам по себе довольно большой. 
Игрок двигается с помощью клавиатуры, но вопрос был немного в другом, как переместить объект именно в то или иное место на карте, то есть не вставить картинку или еще что - либо, а уже с помощью зарезервированной функции в sfml указать позицию на карте объекту.
Саму карту я делал через String, поэтому там объекты легко расставить, а как переместить игрока при столкновении с объектом в какое -либо место - вопрос. И как в итоге вывести большой текст на экран, так же при столкновении с объектом

Comment: *"указать позицию на карте объекту"* Что вы называете объектом? `sf::Sprite`? Какой-то свой класс? Без кода ничего не понятно. *"довольно большой"* Ну загрузили бы на гитхаб.

Comment: Объект это класс. Class Player.

Comment: Ну, в нем ведь хранятся координаты? Нельзя просто их поменять, чтобы телепортировать игрока? Проще покажите код.

Answer (score 1):

sfml - это не игровой движок, а обертка над различными мультимедийными API, предоставляющая базовые функции в единообразной манере. Соответственно всю игровую логику необходимо реализовывать самостоятельно.